# How to traverse a tree of permission groups with dependencies

Tags: java, tree, dependencies, graph-theory

Using Java, I am writing a simple user permissions system where permissions are defined as short strings (for example, the permission "REBOOT" allows the user to reboot). Each user can be assigned to multiple groups if needed (for example, they may be a VIP and a Moderator).

As a simple example with just a few groups:

```
- Administrators
Inherits from: Moderators, VIP
Permissions: ["REBOOT", "PERMA_BAN"]

- Moderators
Inherits from: Default
Permissions: ["TEMP_BAN", "KICK"]

- VIP
Inherits from: Default
Permissions: ["NO_POST_LIMIT"]

- Default
Inherits from: *None*
Permissions: ["POST", "PRIVATE_MESSAGE"]
```

Administrators have permissions from Moderators and VIP explicitly, and from Default implicitly (as Moderator/VIP both inherit from Default). That means when the code resolves all of their permission strings, all of the permissions will be present from every group in their permission list. Moderators have permissions from just Default, but not VIP, as they only inherit from Default... so they will only have their group's permissions and the Default permissions.

This is representable by a graph (where edges represent dependencies): [Graph with group inheritance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWq0h.png)

How can I create this graph in Java and load the groups in the correct order so that the inheritance/dependencies are available when the groups are loaded?

In this example, Default is loaded first as it has no dependencies, then Moderators and VIP as they only need Default, and finally Administrators as it needs all 3 other groups to load?

Comment: Check [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).